# Globally Disable Nag modals "Leave Site" "Changes may not be saved" Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, tampermonkey

How can I globally and PERMANENTLY disable chromes ability to open

"Leave Site?" "Changes may not be saved" popups.

I want to close every tab of every chrome window and I know what I'm doing I don't need the nanny app to prevent my shutdown or get in my way when I'm trying to close out.

I tried tampermonkey scripts for disabling "onbeforeunload" events but they're not stopping this obnoxious behavior from chrome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Install a `beforeunload` listener before the page does by declaring `@run-at document-start` in the metadata block.
2. Call `stopImmediatePropagation` to prevent the subsequently added page listeners from seeing the event.
3. Also clear `window.onbeforeunload`.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        ignore beforeunload 
// @match       *://*/*
// @grant       none
// @run-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript==

window.addEventListener('beforeunload', e => {
  window.onbeforeunload = null;
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```